# MySQL: What if I only want to select by distinct for 1 field?

Tags: mysql

This is my SQL right now:
`SELECT Persons, Color, Race, Game FROM table`

So I want to select unique `Persons`, so I would do:
`SELECT DISTINCT Persons FROM table`

The problem with that is, its not selecting the rest. How can I select ONLY `Persons` by distinct and select the rest normally (in 1 sql command, if possible)?

Answer (score 4):

mysql lets you just do:

```
select Persons, Color, Race, Game FROM table GROUP BY Persons
```

You will get the Color, Race, and Game from an arbitrary one of the records with a given Persons.

If you want e.g. all the Color values for a given Persons, you would need to do something like:

```
select Persons, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Color), ...
```

This will return a comma (or other separator if you request) separated list of the distinct Color values for each Persons.  A maximum length may be imposed; that can be changed via a server configuration variable.

Comment: +1 presuming that the OP is ok with getting some random value for color, race and game. If not, the OP needs to put in specifics regarding how to retrieve color, race and game

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use standard-ish SQL, consider using:

```
SELECT Person, MAX(Color) AS Color, MAX(Race) AS Race, MAX(Game) AS Game
  FROM table
 GROUP BY Person;
```

This is semi-trivial variation on the answer provided by [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth), but it will work with DBMS other than MySQL.  The values you get for Color, Race, Game are determinate but the values shown need not all come from the same record (if the given Person has more than one record in table).

Clearly, if you want the Color, Race and Game values to shown to come from a single row of the table, you have to work (a lot) harder.  All else apart, you have devise a criterion to choose which row you want selected.